# After upgrading to Qgis 2.14 Essen, cannot load layers from .zip

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I had a project in 2.12 Lyon that used many .zip files for access to .shp files.  Now, after upgrading, I cannot add any content from .zip.  This is Win10 Machine and I have the option checked to scan contents of .zip (FULL SCAN)  I cannot access my old zip files for my layers, nor can I access any new downloaded content.

Comment: Believe this is a bug (same with loading .kmz files, kml is okay) add bug/issue to http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report and not a question for GIS.SE, please report it at http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues